# How to diagnose Google Drive file uploading failure after successful file creation?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

An Android app essentially follows [the official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#multipart) to do the file uploading.

```
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
...
File fileData = new File(pathLocalFile);
FileContent fileContent = new FileContent("file/binary", fileData);
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = googleDriveService.files().create(fileMetadata, fileContent)
                                        .setFields("*")
                                        .execute();
```

I want to emphasize the above code works flawlessly on most devices. However, on some Android devices, the file is created correctly on Google Drive, but no data are uploaded. No exceptions are thrown. Could anyone offer a tip about how to diagnose this?

Comment: If you have one of the offending devices at your disposal, maybe you may want to try a network monitor tool for Android. Have a look at these [Wireshark alternatives for Android](https://alternativeto.net/software/wireshark/?platform=android).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It seems that the issue is related to some specific user accounts.